# Cyclic extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ and primitive element

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb Q_p$ be the unique unramified extension of degree $n$. By the primitive element theorem, there exists some $\alpha \in K$ such that $\{1, \alpha, \dots, \alpha^{n-1}\}$ is a $\mathbb Q_p$-basis for $K$. The Galois group $G = \operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q_p)$ is cyclic of order $n$. We pick a generator $\sigma$.

Can we describe $\sigma(\alpha)$ explicitly?

An answer to this question depends on making choices for $\alpha$ and for $\sigma$, of which the choice of $\alpha$ seems to be more complicated. Is there some distinguished choice of $\alpha$ allowing for an answer to the above question?

Answer (score 1):

One can choose $\alpha=\zeta_{p^n-1}$, then $\sigma$ can be taken to the Frobenius, i.e. $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha^p$. Other choices of $\sigma$ will lead to powers of the Frobenius.